# Specflow Generateall verbose

Tags: teamcity, specflow

I run 1000s of tests using specflow 2.0 and team city.
Currently due to the amount of tests it often takes to the end of a run to realise that some tests failed to generate.
I want to know if its possible to get the verbose output of the GenerateAll command for the generation of tests to save to a notepad file or interact with it directly with code in the project. This way we can run the output through some basic code to tell us how many tests failed to generate

Im not sure if its as simple as adding something to the command line or more complex so im not sure what additional info to provide.

Comment: You mean running the `specflow.exe generateall` command, right? Can you post more information about your TeamCity build? If the `specflow.exe generateall` command returns a non 0 (zero) error code, then you can assume the command did not run properly.

Comment: Yes i do mean that. It does work correctly because the verbose output is in the build log. ive been tasked with generating a simplified report of tests that generated vs ons that failed based on that output but im not sure how to access it programmatically.

Comment: I take it you are not including the .feature.cs files in version control? Did you try checking the `%errorLevel%` variable after running the command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MSBuild Generation to generate the code-behind files. With that, you get the errors as normal build errors.

If you are on SpecFlow >= 2.3, you can simply add the `SpecFlow.Tools.MSBuild.Generation` NuGet to your project and that should it be.

If you are on some earlier version, it is more complicated. So the best would be to update to the latest SpecFlow version.

Detailed documentation can be found here: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Tools/Generate-Tests-From-MsBuild.html